# Tomcat 7 and Oracle Connection Pooling

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat

I am attempting to use connection pooling with tomcat 7 and connecting to an Oracle database. At the minute my context looks like this

```
<Resource 
     type="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
     driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
     factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
     url="my-url" 
     username="username"
     password="password"
```

I am using google guice to inject the DataSource,

```
bind(Context.class).to(InitialContext.class);
bind(DataSource.class).toProvider(fromJndi(OracleDataSource.class,"java:comp/env/jdbc/nameToUse"));
```

however it does appear to be creating the provider, but anytime it calls it I always get a RunTime error with

javax.naming.NamingException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

even though the login details are definitely correct - they work if I switch back to the old way of connecting to the database. Am I doing something wrong, with Guice, or is the connection pool with Oracle (9i I believe) setup differently?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: are your username and password in quotes? if so remove them.

Comment: nope, no quotes around them - the exact same username and passwords work whenever I revert back to the old context.xml 

              type="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              factory="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSourceFactory"

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the username and password in the URL - in addition to setting username and password attributes in the Resource element.

E.g.

```
<Resource 
 type="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
 driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
 factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
 url="jdbc:oracle:thin:joebob/jbpass@mydbhost.example.com:1521/db"
 username="joebob"
 password="jbpass" ... />
```